# How do I fix my method so that all powers of base 2 are display not the sum?

Tags: java, methods

```
public static String allPowers(long a, long b) {
        String powers = "";
        long number = a;

        while (number <= b) {

            powers = Math.pow(2, number) + " ";
            number++;
        }
        return powers;
    }
```

I am trying to have String
so that I get 2^2, 2^3.......2^6.
But instead I am getting a sum 64
which anyways is wrong 
the sum should be 124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` object:

```
public static String allPowers(long a, long b)
{
    StringBuilder powers = new StringBuilder();
    long number = a;
    while (number <= b)
    {
        powers.append(Math.pow(2, number)).append(" ");
        number++;
    }
    return powers.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite `powers` in every iteration. You should append the string with `powers += Math.pow(2, number) + " ";` or use a `StringBuilder` (prefered, because string concatenation creates new objects every iteration).